# Specialized class member function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to use a specialized class member function. I have found the following solution in one post here but it doesn't work with me.
When I build the solution I receive the following errors:
- TestClass.obj : error LNK2005 and fatal error LNK1169.
What is wrong with my code?

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class TestClass
{
    private:
    VD cdata;
    public:
    TestClass(void){}; 
    TestClass(VD & edata);
    T1 fun1(const T2 ex);
    ~TestClass(void);
};

  template <class T1, class T2>
  T1 TestClass<T1, T2>::fun1(const T2 x)
  {
     T1 v1 = 100.0*pow(x[1] - x[0]*x[0],2) + pow(1 - x[0],2);
     return v1;
  }


 template <>
 double TestClass<double, column_vector>::fun1(const column_vector x)
 {
    double v1 = 100.0*pow(x(1) - x(0)*x(0),2) + pow(1 - x(0),2);
    return v1;
 }
```

Comment: Are you putting those in a .cpp file?

Comment: I'm sorry I have solved the problem, I didn't eliminate from the project an empty .cpp file. Thank you Andy Prowl for the suggestion.

Comment: @dds ss: An empty `.cpp` file will not cause LNK2005 or LNK1169. That file had nothing to do with the error. In any case, you have to post full error messages. Which function is mentioned in LNK2005 and which function is mentioned in LNK1169???

Answer (score 1):

An explicitly specialized (i.e. fully specialized) template function is an *ordinary* function for ODR purposes. This means that you have to *declare* your specialization in the header file without defining it

```
template <>
double TestClass<double, column_vector>::fun1(const column_vector x);
```

and then define it in some `.cpp` file

```
template <>
double TestClass<double, column_vector>::fun1(const column_vector x)
{
  double v1 = 100.0*pow(x(1) - x(0)*x(0),2) + pow(1 - x(0),2);
  return v1;
}
```

You put the whole definition into the header file, which produced a multiple-definition error (LNK1169).

As for LNK2005... you have to supply more information. It is not clear from what you posted who could've caused LNK2005. Which function is mentioned by LNK2005?